# Is there a way to find the source code for official android apps?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've found the platform package on github but some of them are very old. Any chance anyone knows where to find the more recent source code?

Comment: Hello. Your question appears to be off-topic and will likely be closed shortly. I recommend that you read about the kinds of questions that are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The home of the source code for the Android Open Source Project is at https://android.googlesource.com/.

If what you want is not there, most likely it is not available as an open source project.

Comment: Can we upload it directly to a project in Android Studio?

Comment: @ashkan117: Typically no, as they are not designed to be built as individual apps. They are designed to be built as part of a firmware image.

Answer (score 0):

you have to deconstruct APKs but when it deconstructs the only thing that are readable there are Latin letters